# Local minimum of a function using the fundamental theorem of calculus

Tags: calculus

I'm just checking my answers to the following question to make sure my reasoning is sound.

I want to find the values of $x$ for where the Fresnel function takes local minimum values. This function being: $\int_{0}^{x} \sin{\frac{\pi t^2}{2}} dt$.

So I used the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus to find the first derivative and from that found the second derivative to be  $\pi x \cos{\frac{\pi x^2}{2}}$. I want this to be greater than zero for local minimum values.

I know from looking at the graph of $\cos(x)$ that it is greater than zero for even multiples of $\pi$ so $\frac{x^2}{2}$ must be even i.e. $x = \sqrt{2m}$ where $m$ is an even positive integer?

Is this correct?

Comment: moony- are you not considering values $x<0$ ? Otherwise its alright.

Comment: Yes, I had though about that but then I saw an example done where the max values were being looked at and  $x < 0$ wasn't considered there either . I'm not sure why.